# How can I schecule kube-system nodes to fargate in AWS EKS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

I deployed a EKS cluster to AWS via terraform. There are two fargate profile, one for `kube-system` the other is `default`. After create the cluster, all pods under `kube-system` are pending. And the error is:

```
$ kubectl get pods -A
NAMESPACE     NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   coredns-6db676b456-694w8   0/1     Pending   0          3m43s
kube-system   coredns-6db676b456-tddtd   0/1     Pending   0          3m43s
kube-system   coredns-b8f47f545-7wzm8    0/1     Pending   0          78m

$ kubectl describe --namespace kube-system pod coredns-6db676b456-694w8
Warning  FailedScheduling  21s (x3 over 92s)  default-scheduler  no nodes available to schedule pods
```

It seems the fargate is not scheculed to these pods. What did I do wrong? Below is the full terrform configuration:

```
resource "aws_eks_cluster" "elk" {
  name     = "elk"
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.elk.arn
  version  = 1.20

  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids = [module.vpc.private_subnets[0], module.vpc.private_subnets[1]]
  }

  # Ensure that IAM Role permissions are created before and deleted after EKS Cluster handling.
  # Otherwise, EKS will not be able to properly delete EKS managed EC2 infrastructure such as Security Groups.
  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.elk-AmazonEKSClusterPolicy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.elk-AmazonEKSVPCResourceController,
  ]
}

output "endpoint" {
  value = aws_eks_cluster.elk.endpoint
}

output "kubeconfig-certificate-authority-data" {
  value = aws_eks_cluster.elk.certificate_authority[0].data
}

# Fargate

resource "aws_eks_fargate_profile" "elk" {
  cluster_name           = aws_eks_cluster.elk.name
  fargate_profile_name   = "elk_profile"
  pod_execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.fargate_profile.arn
  subnet_ids             = [module.vpc.private_subnets[0], module.vpc.private_subnets[1]]

  selector {
    namespace = "default"
  }
}

resource "aws_eks_fargate_profile" "kube_system" {
  cluster_name           = aws_eks_cluster.elk.name
  fargate_profile_name   = "kube_system_profile"
  pod_execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.fargate_profile.arn
  subnet_ids             = [module.vpc.private_subnets[0], module.vpc.private_subnets[1]]

  selector {
    namespace = "kube-system"
  }
}

# IAM Role

resource "aws_iam_role" "elk" {
  name = "eks-cluster-elk"

  assume_role_policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "eks.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "elk-AmazonEKSClusterPolicy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSClusterPolicy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.elk.name
}

# Optionally, enable Security Groups for Pods
# Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/security-groups-for-pods.html
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "elk-AmazonEKSVPCResourceController" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSVPCResourceController"
  role       = aws_iam_role.elk.name
}

# IAM role for service account

data "tls_certificate" "elk" {
  url = aws_eks_cluster.elk.identity[0].oidc[0].issuer
}

resource "aws_iam_openid_connect_provider" "elk" {
  client_id_list  = ["sts.amazonaws.com"]
  thumbprint_list = [data.tls_certificate.elk.certificates[0].sha1_fingerprint]
  url             = aws_eks_cluster.elk.identity[0].oidc[0].issuer
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "elk_assume_role_policy" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"]
    effect  = "Allow"

    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "${replace(aws_iam_openid_connect_provider.elk.url, "https://", "")}:sub"
      values   = ["system:serviceaccount:kube-system:aws-node"]
    }

    principals {
      identifiers = [aws_iam_openid_connect_provider.elk.arn]
      type        = "Federated"
    }
  }
}

# resource "aws_iam_role" "elk" {
#   assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.elk_assume_role_policy.json
#   name               = "elk"
# }

# IAM role for fargate profile

resource "aws_iam_role" "fargate_profile" {
  name = "eks-fargate-profile"

  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Statement = [{
      Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
      Effect = "Allow"
      Principal = {
        Service = "eks-fargate-pods.amazonaws.com"
      }
    }]
    Version = "2012-10-17"
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "AmazonEKSFargatePodExecutionRolePolicy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSFargatePodExecutionRolePolicy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.fargate_profile.name
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that you need to patch the CoreDNS deployment. By default it is configured to only run on worker nodes and not on Fargate. See the "(Optional) Update CoreDNS" section in this [doc page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate-getting-started.html)